# Webpack output file to have exports default instead of module.exports

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a case where I need webpack to create a file using `export` syntax and not `module.exports`. Is this possible?

Here's my config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./node/example.js",
  node: {
    console: true,
    global: true,
    process: true,
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true,
    Buffer: true,
    setImmediate: true,
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'example.js',
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs-module'
  },
  resolve: {
    // options for resolving module requests
    // (does not apply to resolving to loaders)
    modules: [
      "node_modules",
      path.resolve(__dirname, "app")
    ],
    // directories where to look for modules
    extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".jsx", ".css"],
  },

  target: "node", // enum  // the environment in which the bundle should run

}
```

> example.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function() {
  return 'hello world';
}
```

What I need webpack to do is export with `export default` rather then `module.exports =`.

Comment: So I understand, you want to compile a CommonJS codebase into one final ESM bundle?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes.

Comment: is this possible?

<script>
import Bam from '/path/to/webpack.bundle.1234.js';
new Bam // SyntaxError: Importing binding name 'default' cannot be resolved by star export entries.
</script>

Answer (score 1):

You can use a transpiler (like Babel) to allow you to use language features that aren't supported by your runtime environment (like `import` and `export` syntax). You can install the required modules with

```
npm i @babel/core @babel/preset-env babel-loader
```

That installs the Babel core, a plugin which transpiles future language features, and the webpack loader to pre-process JS files with Babel.

Then, you'll need a `.babelrc` config file in your root project directory. In this case it just needs to contain the following

```
{"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]}
```

That tells Babel you want to use the "preset env." plugin to transpile your `import` and `export` statements, among other things.

Finally, you need to tell Webpack to use Babel to load JS files. You can do this by adding a `module.rules` list to your Webpack config like so.

```
node: { /* ... */ },
module: {
    rules: [
        {test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think you jumped the gun on this explanation, this explains how to load in files and build from babel files, I am not doing that. I am actually loading in es5 files. However I need webpack to export a bundle that uses `export` syntax. I know this case is very unconventional. I am questioning if webpack has the ability to do this.

Comment: Ah gotcha, you're wondering about webpack support for es6 modules. [this](https://medium.com/@svinkle/getting-started-with-webpack-and-es6-modules-c465d053d988) would seem to imply that they're supported out of the box